# How can I build, in JavaScript a filter chain, in the style of lodash's wrap?

Tags: javascript, lodash, ecmascript-2016

To be clear, given an Array of Objects, likely with homogenous keys:

```
const data = [
  { name: "tomato", isHealthy: true, "calories": 300 },
  { name: "french fries", isHealthy: false, "calories": 1000 },
  { name: "lettuce", isHealthy: true, "calories": 100 },
  { name: "nacho cheese", isHealthy: false, "calories": 1200 },
  { name: "boring chicken", isHealthy: true, "calories": 500 },
];
```

and a few filters say:

```
const isHealthy = function(items) {
  return items.filter(i => i.isHealthy);
};

const caloriesAbove = function(items, calories) {
  return items.filter(i => i.calories > calories);
};
```

I'd like to be able to call the filter chain like:

`wrapper(data).isHealthy().caloriesAbove(500).value.map(...)`

It is a bit difficult to see how lodash accomplishes this. Further, is there a way to do this w/o having to explicitly unwrap in order to get the value? This is not a requirement as I think this might have to use undesirable hacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how lodash does it:

```
 function wrapper(items) {
    return {
        value: items,
        isHealthy() { 
          return wrapper(items.filter(it => it.isHealthy));
        },
        caloriesAbove(calories) {
          return wrapper(items.filter(it => it.calories > calories));
        },
    };
 }
```

> Further, is there a way to do this w/o having to explicitly unwrap in order to get the value?

Since ES6 you can extend arrays:

```
  class Items extends Array {
    isHealthy() {
      return this.filter(it => it.isHealthy);
    }
  }
```

To turn an existing array into Items, just do `Items.from(array)` or `new Items(...array)` then you can:

```
  items
    .filter(it => it.calories > 2) // native methods can be used, they return Item instances, not Arrays
    .isHealthy() // our custom methods also work
    .map(it => it.name)[0] //its a regular array with indices.
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the answer and I loved the way this was done by @Jonas. Did not know that you can simply extend the Array like that. Def. got my upvote!

With that being said I was wondering how more useful that approach is when you can simply create a filter function to handle multiple values and pass it to the filter of the array:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "tomato", isHealthy: true, "calories": 300 },
  { name: "french fries", isHealthy: false, "calories": 1000 },
  { name: "lettuce", isHealthy: true, "calories": 100 },
  { name: "nacho cheese", isHealthy: false, "calories": 1200 },
  { name: "boring chicken", isHealthy: true, "calories": 500 },
];

const myFilterFn = ({isHealthy, calories}) => isHealthy && calories > 200

data.filter(myFilterFn).map(x => console.log(x))
```

I see the value of this in a more generic view but for filtering it seems little bit of an overkill.

Just my 2 cents.